# DBCA Permission Denied

Tags: virtualbox, oracle18c, dbca

I'm new on Linux environment.
For this task, I am using Centos 7 in VirtualBox and trying to follow the guide to install Oracle Database 18c XE.
After setting the config and profile, I finally get the oracle to work.
However, when I tried to create a new Database via dbca, the following error prompted.

```
[project@localhost bin]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
[project@localhost bin]$ cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
[project@localhost bin]$ dbca
bash: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/dbca: Permission denied
```

I've only created 1 user (project) for this practicing purpose.

Comment: I can't tell your entire setup from what you've provided, but it appears you are running dbca as the "project" user. dbca must generally be run by the same user which owns the Oracle software binaries. By default on Linux that is the "oracle" user. Does "project" actually own the Oracle installation on your system?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i didn't recognize user oracle was created. Now I've su oracle to launch the dbca